# formatting number in joomla k2 extrafields

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-k2

I want to show some extrafields in k2 component (version : 2.6) of joomla (version :2.5.17) with thousand separator , in Item view and Category view , How can I?

Comment: no one knows anything?

Comment: What about playing with the given information in your k2 custom templates ?

Comment: what is your mean exactly shaz?

Comment: You can use some number / string manipulation in the k2 template (override).

Answer (score 0):

In your custom K2 template file item.php, try the following code:

```
<?php foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField): ?>
<?php if($extraField->value): ?>
<?php echo $extraField->value; ?>, 
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Was this answer able to help you?